# I want prove uniform electric field work : I know that $\mathbf{F}(t)=Q\mathbf{E}(t)$

Tags: calculus, physics

I want prove uniform electric field work : I know that $\mathbf{F}(t)=Q\mathbf{E}(t)$ but is uniform So $\mathbf{F}=Q\mathbf{E}$
Thus we have  : 
$$
\begin{aligned}
W_{(t_a -t_b)}&:=\int_{t_a}^{t_b} \Big( \mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \dfrac{d}{dt}\mathbf{r}(t) \Big) \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_{t_a}^{t_b} \Big(Q\mathbf{E}(t)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dt}\mathbf{r}(t) \Big) \mathrm{d}t\\
&=Q\int_{t_a}^{t_b} \Big(\Big(E_x(t) \mathbf{i} +E_y(t) \mathbf{j}+E_z(t) \mathbf{k}\Big)\cdot \Big (\dfrac{d}{dt}r_x(t)\mathbf{i}+\dfrac{d}{dt}r_y(t)\mathbf{j}+\dfrac{d}{dt}r_z(t)\mathbf{k}\Big)\Big) \mathrm{d}t \\
&=Q\int_{t_a}^{t_b} \Big(E_x(t) \dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_x(t) +E_y(t) \dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_y(t) +E_z(t)\dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_z(t)  \Big) \mathrm{d}t\\
&= Q\int_{t_a}^{t_b}  \Big(E_x\dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_x(t) + E_y\dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_y(t) +E_z\dfrac{d}{dt}{r}_z(t)  \Big) \mathrm{d}t \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now what ?

Comment: Almot.Integrating you get $Q\vec E \cdot (\vec r(t_b)-\vec r(t_a))$.Wrong?

Comment: @PeterSzilas how $Q \vec{E}\cdot (\vec{r}(t_b)-\vec{r}(t_a)) ?$

Comment: Almot.$E_x \int_{t_a}^{t_b} d(r_x(t))/dt =$ $E_x(r_x(t_b)-r_x(t_a))$, other components likewise, in the end you write it as a scalar product again.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the constant ${\bf E}$ out of the integral and write
$$W_{(t_a, \,t_b)}=Q{\bf E}\cdot\int_{t_a}^{t_b}{d\over dt}{\bf r}(t)\>dt=Q{\bf E}\cdot\bigl({\bf r}(t_b)-{\bf r}(t_a)\bigr)\ .$$
Note that the function
$${\bf r}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t),z(t)\bigr)\qquad(t_a\leq t\leq t_b)$$
has no partial derivatives with respect to $x$,$y$, $z$, but just a time derivative
$$\dot{\bf r}(t)=\bigl(\dot x(t),\dot y(t),\dot z(t)\bigr)\ .$$